# PHP PDO MSSQL: created temp table does not exist

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, temp-tables

When I use mysqli I do:

```
$mysqli->query('create temporary table __tmp(tm_start int, tm_end int, tm_origin int, tm_num int)');
$mysqli->query('insert into  __tmp values 
( 1447977600, 1448582400, 1447977600, 0 ),
( 1448582400, 1449187200, 1448582400, 1 )');
$result=$mysqli->query('select * from __tmp');
```

and get what I've just inserted.

But when I use similar code with PDO connected to MSSQL:

```
$pdo->query("create table #__tmp(tm_start int, tm_end int, tm_origin int, tm_num int)");
$pdo->query('insert into  #__tmp values 
    ( 1447977600, 1448582400, 1447977600, 0 ),
    ( 1448582400, 1449187200, 1448582400, 1 )');
```

the second query returns error **table does not exist**. 
I assumed that everything after '*$pdo=new PDO(...)*' will be the same session, like in mysqli, and temporary tables will be killed only after '*$pdo=null*'.

Maybe I must explicitely tell PDO to execute all queries keeping the same connection? Something like 'keep-alive' flag? Transactions seem excessive for my needs.

I know about global temp tables (##), but another session of this same user can access/modify these tables and we'll have concurrency problems.

If I'll use persistent connection it will hang and again any user can connect to it and again concurrency.

I'd like not to use stored procedures either. I have to maintain two classes (mysql and mssql based) for the same tasks, so I want to keep all sql logic in php.

Comment: Batch finished - table is gone. Do your work in same batch or use ## (with more unique name than "tmp").

Comment: what is a batch in this context? string passed to $dbo->query(...) ? Can't work in same batch then, there are many queries, several temp tables created and they all used in several intermediate and final selects. Yes, currently I'm using global temps with mt_rand-based names, and check before create them. But it's very interesting why temp tables do not survive dbo object lifetime? And why they do in mysqli?

Comment: By design. What else to say?

Comment: Did you try to use PHP with Non Thread compiling?